# How to get a value in <td> tag

Tags: javascript, html

```
<td id="hello"> OPD </td>
```

On my html page, this is how I am getting a td tag in a tr.

I want to get the value "OPD" in java script variable.

```
var td1 = document.getElementById("hello");
```

Can I get this value by performing any operation on td1.

Is there any other way to do this. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var td1 = (document.getElementById("hello")).innerHTML;
```

or

```
var td1 = ((document.getElementById("hello")).innerHTML).trim();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
td1.innerHTML
```

should work. [InnerHtml](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:element.innerHTML)

Comment: Technically should also call `.trim()`. Otherwise +1.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this:

- Either you use a [DOM-Shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim) and just the following:

  ```
  var td1 = document.getElementById('hello').textContent
  ```
- Or you don't want to use a shim, then you have to use the following (thank IE):

  ```
  var hello = document.getElementById('hello'),
      td1
  if ('textContent' in hello) {
      td1 = hello.textContent // Standard way
  }
  else {
      td1 = hello.innerText // IE way
  }
  ```
- Or you use jQuery:

  ```
  var td1 = $('#hello').text()
  ```

However, don't use innerHTML. This is just bad for many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in a jQuery answer...

```
var tdText = $('#hello').text();
```

or

```
var tdTextTrimmed = $.trim($('#hello').text());
```